# Saving to internal memory android

Tags: java, android, image, save

I'm having trouble getting an image to save to internal memory on my device. I've looked at other topics and implemented them, but nothing has worked for me. If anyone can point me in the right direction it would be appreciated. I also can't save the image to an sd card as my tablet does not have one. Here's my code

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.ContextWrapper;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
// Request codes for Activities
private static final int CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST = 100;
private static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
private static final int LINK_TO_DROPBOX = 150;

// Directory name to store captured images
private static String IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME = "Android to Dropbox";

// Uri to store images
private Uri fileUri;

private ImageView imagePreview; // To preview image
private Button captureImage;    // To launch camera intent
private Button linkDropbox;     // Link users Dropbox account

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    imagePreview = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imagePrview);
    captureImage = (Button)findViewById(R.id.imageCapture);
    linkDropbox = (Button)findViewById(R.id.linkToDropbox);

    // Go to method to start camera intent to capture image
    captureImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            captureImage();
        }
    });

    // Check if user is connected to their Dropbox account
    linkDropbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            linkToDropbox();
        }
    });
}// End onCreate

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
{
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putParcelable("file_uri", fileUri);
}// End onSavedInstanceState

// Restore fileUri
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    fileUri = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("file_uri");
}// End onRestoreInstanceState

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}// End onCreateOptionsMenu

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if(requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST)
    {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) // Successfully captured image
            previewCapturedImage();
        else if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED)  // User cancelled image capture
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User cancelled image capture", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        else    // Failed to capture image
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed to capture image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}// End onActivityResult

// Method to launch camera within app
private void captureImage()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST);
}// End captureImage

// Check if user has linked to their Dropbox account
private void linkToDropbox()
{

}// End linkToDropbox

// Preview captured image
private void previewCapturedImage()
{
    try
    {
        imagePreview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);   // Show ImageView

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = 8;

        final Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileUri.getPath(), options);
        imagePreview.setImageBitmap(image);
        saveToInternalMemory(image); // TRY TO SAVE IMAGE IN INTERNAL MEMORY
    }
    catch(NullPointerException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}// End previewCapturedImage

// Method to save image to inernal memory
public void saveToInternalMemory(Bitmap image)
{
    boolean ableToSave = true;
    File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
    if(pictureFile == null)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed to save image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        ableToSave = false;
    }

    if(ableToSave)
    {
        try
        {
            FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
            image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
            stream.close();
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error accessing file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}// End saveToInternalMemory

// Create file uri to store image
public Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type)
{
    return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
}// End getOutputMediaFileUri

// Return image
private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type)
{
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME);
    File mediaFile;

    if(!mediaStorageDir.exists())
    {
        if(!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs())
        {
            Log.d(IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME, "Failed to create " + IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME + " directory");
            mediaFile = null;
        }
    }

    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date()); // Image name

    if(type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE)
    {
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
    }
    else
        mediaFile = null;

    return mediaFile;
}// End getOutputMediaFile

}// End MainActivity
```

EDIT: Looks like this code was working for me. The pictures don't show up on my device unless I'd restart it then they would appear in my photos application.

Comment: You need to specify what problem exactly you are facing. Also copying all your code here just makes it hard for people to read and understand. Please include only the parts that you have trouble with.

Comment: Did you find any solution ? i am stuck in same problem. i can write the image to external storage bit not internal :(

Answer (score 1):

Saving:

```
FileOutputStream outStream = null;
File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File dir = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/YourFolderName");
dir.mkdirs();
String fileName = String.format("%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis());
File outFile = new File(dir, fileName);
outStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outStream);
outStream.flush();
outStream.close();
```

Give manifest permissions and also, Go to Device Settings>Device>Applications>Application Manager>"your app">Permissions>Enable Storage permission!

Answer (score 0):

In your save method, try doing this:

```
String FILENAME = "hello_file";

FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
fos.close();
```

See the developer docs for more information.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal

Another note for why your current code might not be working - in your `getOutputMediaFile` method, you're creating a new file using the external storage directory:

`Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory`